# What is the correct data type in sql for the input of 1,084

Tags: sql, datatable

I have an assignment which needs to find all the CondoFees between $600 and $700. The lowest the data goes is $190 and the highest it goes is $670. The data type I am currently using is decimal(6,2) and ive tried other sized decimals as well but everytime when i put in the code

```
SELECT LocatioNum, UnitNum
FROM condo_unit
WHERE CondoFee BETWEEN '$600' AND '$700'
```

It prints the table out with 3 condofees that are inbetween $600 and $700 but also prints out one that is only $300.

Does anyone know what might be causing this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the single quotes and dollar sign:

```
where condofee between 600 and 700
```

If you start mixing up data types, then strange things can happen.

Comment: Yes thank you so much! Should I delete the dollar sign in the table its self as well?

Comment: @HarryBrown . . . If the data type is `decimal(6, 2)`, then no dollar sign is being stored.

Comment: To store the dollar sign what would it need to be?

Comment: @HarryBrown . . . `money`, if your database has such a type, or a string.